# WPF System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Invalid window handle

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm getting the following error on WPF.
I'm using MVVM databinding to DataContext + CollectionViewSources on the Window.
There is too much code in the View Model and View to post, but I'm wondering where to look to find this as no line number comes up.

The window is using WPF databinding with converters, some Telerik controls in there also.

This is after calling

```
TabItemSelectionEditor.UpdateLayout()
```

TabItemSelectionEditor is a System.Windows.Control.TabItem

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Invalid window
>   handle
>
> at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(HandleRef hWnd,
>   StringBuilder lpString, Int32 nMaxCount)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Automation.Peers.WindowAutomationPeer.GetNameCore()
>
> at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
>
> at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireAutomationEvents()
>
> at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
>
> at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_7()
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>
> at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)

Inner Exception is nothing!

Comment: Anything else to go on--there's really not much there even to guess at.  That seems like the stack for handling the exception--not the stack that caused the exception.  Is there an inner exception?  What *that* the inner exception?

Comment: I've just added a few more details.

Comment: I'm seeing a very problem and I have no idea where this is coming from:

Type: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: Cannot create a file when that file already exists
StackTrace:    at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(HandleRef hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, Int32 nMaxCount)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.WindowAutomationPeer.GetNameCore()
...
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: I am seeing exactly same exception as @Volker von Einem. I have no idea why. Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you not have a `DisplayClass` method in your code?

I can also see that there is a `VirtualizingStackPanel` involved and the error occurred when it called the `UIElement.UpdateLayout()` method on its children.

That's about all that I can work out from this error and without any more information, I can't help any further.

Comment: I have a .Show() method on my ViewModel, which created the view and displays it.  Is this what you mean by a DisplayClass method?

Comment: Nope. It was just a guess, but you're saying that you have no class, method, or custom object called `DisplayClass` anywhere in the application? It was because of the line in the error where it says `DisplayClass`... this is *not* a method of the `VirtualizingStackPanel` class, so I assumed that it was from *your* code.

Comment: Maybe that is in the Telerik code? As I'm using some Telerik stuff inside that Tab Item.

Comment: It could well be from Telerik... maybe you should contact them?

Comment: Hey I removed Telerik and switched to built in .NET WPF TabControl and same issue.