# WPF application crashes when connected via Teamviewer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, teamviewer

I have a problem when connecting with teamviewer to the device on which my WPF appliction is running. If this connection is made, my WPF application crashes with the following exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Cannot create a file when that file already exists
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(HandleRef hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, Int32 nMaxCount)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.WindowAutomationPeer.GetNameCore()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireAutomationEvents()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.AnimatedRenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
```

This problem seems to be the same as described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975982/fullscreen-wpf-app-crashes-when-connected-via-teamviewer).

In the comments on this question, usage of the clipboard is mentioned as a possible cause of this problem. But my WPF application does not use the clipboard.

I hope someone can help me finding the cause of this exception.

Comment: From the comments in the linked SO question, and the exception trace, I'd say the app is trying to access some win32 functionality and TeamViewer isn't having any of it. Can you try to catch the exception when it's thrown and find some more info? You may also want to remove your company name from the stack trace.

Comment: I think some more info is needed,e.g. the fragment of code where that exception is thrown

Comment: 1 - did you try with a simple test application ?  2- in your case the app is allready running and crash when you create the remote connection ?

Comment: I am having the very same problem. Can't track it down. Obviously this is something between WPF and TeamViewer, because I don't see any of my own classes or methods included in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this problem myself. It was caused by an empty title of the MainWindow. After setting it, the problem is fixed.